# Is the result of static_casting a constexpr void* a constant expression?

Tags: c++, clang, language-lawyer, c++14, constexpr

clang is rejecting this code which gcc allows:

```
int main() {
    static constexpr const void *vp = nullptr;
    static constexpr const char *cp = static_cast<const char*>(vp);
}
```

With the following:

```
error: constexpr variable 'cp' must be initialized by a constant expression
  static constexpr const char *cp = static_cast<const char*>(vp);
```

After reading the final listing in [N3797](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf) 5.9/2 I don't see anything that forbids `static_cast`'s use in a constant expression.  Am I looking in the wrong place or misreading something? Or should I open a bug against clang?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the C++14 standard (and your (non-final) draft!) mandates that

> A *conditional-expression* `e` is a core constant expression unless
>   the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine
>   (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> — a conversion from type *cv* `void *` to a pointer-to-object type;

Comment: I was looking too hard for `static_cast` that I missed that line.  embarrassing, thank you.  In other news, I need to find the actual final draft

Comment: I thought 3797 was the final draft, do you happen to know the number of the right one?

Comment: @RyanHaining N3936, or N4141, or N4140 (which got some extra editorial changes).